# Suspected bug in Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer.GetPartSize() in win7

Tags: .net, winforms

I think there is a bug in `System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer.GetPartSize()`.

Found through this [link](http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/discussions/226996).  I created a sample console application that calls this method and prints the width and height of the Size object returned, to the console. Below are some results from our office:

- Vista: Width=20, Height=21
- XP:    Width=15, Height=20
- Win7:  Width=7,  Height=21  <--- width returned is wrong

The code is shown below:

```
var element = VisualStyleElement.ComboBox.DropDownButton.Normal;
var renderer = new System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer(element);

var control = new Control();
using (var gr = control.CreateGraphics())
{
    var size = renderer.GetPartSize(gr, ThemeSizeType.True);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Width={0},Height={1}", size.Width, size.Height));
}
```

I can't find anything on the web to indicate that this is a known problem. Any reason to suspect that it's not?!

More importantly, do you think it's safe to just check whether the OS is Win7 and return the correct size instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I get too, 7 x 21:

[image]

Yup, that arrow is exactly 7 pixels wide.  If you want to measure the size to the left and the right of the arrow then you can use these elements:

```
        var left = VisualStyleElement.CreateElement("COMBOBOX", 7, 1);
        var right = VisualStyleElement.CreateElement("COMBOBOX", 6, 1);
```

Present in .NET 4 but hidden because they are not compatible across operating systems.  Values are respectively (6,21) and (5,21) on my machine.

Comment: But the height isn't 21 pixels is it?! Still not sure why on XP its 15x16, Vista 20x21, and Win7 7x21 - the ratio is all wrong...

Comment: Erm, you accepted the 'it's a bug' answer.  I showed you how to arrive at the 18x21 measurement.  If you don't want to use it then good luck with it.

Comment: sorry I hadn't really appreciated your answer at the time. Just read back over it and yes - you have indeed answered my question and given me a workaround as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds similar to the issue in this [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/95321/getpartsize-method-on-the-visualstylerenderer-does-not-return-correct-width-of-a-combobox-dropdownbutton) on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed look like the same problem. Cheers for finding the link

Comment: It is a bug report from *2005*

Comment: @Hans - I noticed that, but it does still say Active, and there's been bugs hanging around for longer than that sometimes, so I thought it might be relevant. However, it was written before you wrote your answer which looks a lot more relevant :)

Comment: @John - I'd suggest changing the accepted answer to Hans answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

There's at least one other person having [the same problem](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr/compatibilite-des-applis-sous-seven/thread/89820ba4-e6cc-4f76-bc7e-888a8666c280).

With enough patience you could take a look at some prominent open source rendering engines (like WebKit, Gecko, Chrome) at find out how they render dropdown buttons (e.g. as part of a combobox). Since they look correct on Windows 7 there must be a workaround or you're doing sth. different.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll have to see if it is worth spending time digging deeper, or just checking for the OS.